# Decoding only one key of Twitter's JSON in PHP and putting it in an array

Tags: php, twitter, json

Using Twitter's search API, I'm being returned a helluva lot of information that is essentially extraneous to me. I'd like to populate an array with *just* the content of the tweets, none of the metadata.

[Here's](http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=laughter&rpp=100&result_type=recent&lang=en) an example of a request and the response. So basically, I'd like to populate an array with the values of the `text` key.

I assume the answer would like in some kind of for loop however I don't know where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

**Convert JSON to Array PHP**

```
<?php
    //get json
    $foo= file_get_contents('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=stackoverflow&rpp=10&result_type=recent&lang=en');

    //convert to array
    $var = json_decode( $foo , true );

    //print array
    print_r( $var );
?>
```

**Convert Array PHP to JSON**

```
<?php
    //declarate array
    $foo = array( 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 , 6 => 7, 8);

    //convert to json
    $var = json_encode( $foo );

    //print json
    print_r( $var );
?>
```

**Read:**

> As of PHP 5.2.0, the JSON extension is bundled and compiled into PHP
>   by default.
>
> See And Read This [JSON PHP Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.json.php)

**AND**

> If you use PHP < 5.2, use JSON [Class Objects](http://pecl.php.net/package/json)

Bye!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do it:

```
<?
    $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=laughter&rpp=100&result_type=recent&lang=en'));
    $l = count($json->results);
    for ($i=0; $i < $l; $i++) { 
        echo $json->results[$i]->text . '<br/>';
    }
?>
```

Note: Use whatever reading method you need if file_get_contents isn't allowed to read remote.